# Total percentages of three input fields

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to set 100% in total on three input fields. So the idea is when the user sets 30 in one field, in the other two automatically to split numbers up to 100. So in the second field needs to be 35 and in the third one 35. Also, if any number is changed after that, the other two will be adjusted accordingly.

The number in any of those three fields can't exceed 100. I think you are getting the idea of what I'm trying to achieve.

Here is what I have tried so far (I'm not so experienced in JavaScript, but I know that this is a bad approach):
`HTML`:

```
<input class="pp-w-100 pp-range-numbers pp-first-field" type="number" name="pp-age-old-2030">
<input class="pp-w-100 pp-range-numbers pp-second-field" type="number" name="pp-age-old-3040">
<input class="pp-w-100 pp-range-numbers pp-third-field" type="number" name="pp-age-old-4050">
```

`JS`:

```
const firstField = document.querySelector('.pp-first-field');
const secondField = document.querySelector('.pp-second-field');
const thirdField = document.querySelector('.pp-third-field');
const totalPercentage = 100;

firstField.addEventListener('change', () => {
    let intValue = parseInt(firstField.value);
    if (intValue < totalPercentage) {
        let getFirstValue = totalPercentage - intValue;
        secondField.value = getFirstValue / 2;
        thirdField.value = getFirstValue / 2;
    }
});

secondField.addEventListener('change', () => {
    let intValue = parseInt(firstField.value) + parseInt(secondField.value);
    if (intValue < totalPercentage) {
        thirdField.value = totalPercentage - intValue;
    }
});
```

The code above is not working as expected.

Thank you.

Comment: This is primarily a math problem I assume. The idea is to 1) get the remaining percentage by subtracting the changed value from 100 2) divide the remaining value by the sum of the two others 3) multiply the two others by the result

Comment: @ChrisG Yes, something like that. But I wasn't able to create it in code.

Comment: Here's one way: https://jsfiddle.net/qepmxr3z/

Comment: @ChrisG Yes, that's work. Thanks! Would you like to submit it as an answer? Also, what is the underscore in `map((_, i) => i)`?

Comment: It's a variable name; I used the underscore to make clear that I'm only using the index. I'm using map to turn `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` into `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` so I don't need the value here.

Comment: Great solution @ChrisG!

Comment: Hey, @ChrisG, I can't type in the field with the current solution. I can only use arrows for the fields. Is there any way to adapt the code to work with typing?

Comment: You can use the `change` event instead of the `input` event. Or you can change the code so it doesn't update all fields, just the others.